# How to determine correct firmware for Creality MB and BLTouch?

Tags: creality-ender-3, firmware, bltouch

I bought motherboard version 4.2.7 and had BLTouch version 3.1

Printer version is probably Creality Ender 3 Pro (although I don't know how it can matter if I got brand new motherboard from Amazon).

On [firmwares page](https://forums.creality3dofficial.com/download/ender-series/ender-3/) I dont see appropriate BLTouch verions. May be I need no firmware upgrade? How to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You linked to the incorrect directory, if your printer is a Creality Ender 3 Pro, the correct location is [this](https://forums.creality3dofficial.com/download/ender-series/ender-3-pro/), here you can find versions of the firmware for your printer type and controller board.

Depending on the version of the touch sensor, you either have or have not got an adapter board. If you have an adaptor board you have the components in the red rectangles:

[image]

If so you need this firmware file: [Ender-3 Pro-4.2.7-TMC2225, Marlin2.0.1-BLTouch-V1.3.1(with adapter board)](https://secureservercdn.net/166.62.109.7/i6h.45f.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/4.2.7V-Ender-3-Pro-32bit-Mainboard-Marlin2.0.1-V1.3.1-BLTouch-TMC2225.rar), otherwise you need this firmware file: [Ender-3 Pro- 4.2.7-TMC2225, Marlin2.0.1-BLTouch-V1.1.2(without adapter board)](https://secureservercdn.net/166.62.109.7/i6h.45f.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Ender-3-Pro-4.2.7-Marlin2.0.1-V1.1.2-BLTouch-TMC2225.rar).

An alternative is to build your own firmware, you then no longer are bound to pre-compiled files from others, the Marlin configuration file for the Ender 3 Pro is found near the Marlin sources, see [here](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Configurations/tree/bugfix-2.1.x/config/examples/Creality/Ender-3%20Pro/CrealityV427), you probably only need to enable the BLTouch in the [configuration file](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Configurations/blob/bugfix-2.1.x/config/examples/Creality/Ender-3%20Pro/CrealityV427/Configuration.h#L1345). There are even more solutions, you can look into TH3D software or many other forks from Marlin on GitHub.